# How to get Pipeline RunID

Tags: c#, azure-data-factory

I am new to Azure and I need to find the Latest Activity RunID of a pipeline in Azure using c#. I don't want to invoke the pipeline instance, simply want to get the last activity RunID. When I tried it is possible to invoke the pipeline and get the ID. Can anyone help me in this?.

Answer (score 3):

The way I found to do this is by querying the data factory instance asking for runs between dates, and then look for the pipeline name in the response list. In c# it would be something like this:

```
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime lastWeek = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        PipelineRunFilterParameters prfp = new PipelineRunFilterParameters(lastWeek, today);

        var x = client.PipelineRuns.QueryByFactory("yourResourceGroupName", "DatafactoryInstanceName", prfp);
        var enumerator = x.Value.GetEnumerator();
        PipelineRun pipeRun;
        string runId;
        string pipeName = "theNameOfYourPipeline";
        while (enumerator.MoveNext())
        {
            pipeRun = enumerator.Current;
            if(pipeRun.PipelineName == pipeName)
            {
                runId = pipeRun.RunId;
                break;
            }
        }
```

This code assumes your pipeline runs on a weekly basis, modify it to meet your needs.

Hope this helped!!