# ADF pipeline - How can I check pipeline run status via c# code (pipeline triggered via a blob trigger)

Tags: c#, automated-tests, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to check the pipeline run status of a specific pipeline via c# code.
The pipeline is triggered via a Blob Events Trigger (Blob Created/File Uploaded via c# code) rather than an API call or DataFactoryManagementClient.Pipelines.CreateRunWithHttpMessagesAsync.

If the pipeline was triggered via code and I had the runId then I'd have simply captured the status from the response using DataFactoryManagementClient.PipelineRuns.GetAsync() method. But i'm trying to get the status from a pipeline triggered via file upload to a Storage container.

I tried to use the answer suggested on [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49405267/how-to-get-pipeline-runid) but it mentions PipelineRunFilterParameters which I can't find the namespace for.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I ask how your c# code know it needs to check for runs? Is it triggered on a schedule? You can always store the run Id you are interested in in a storage somewhere or trigger your code by http, this will require a change to the ADF pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can use datafactory API

First get runs on the pipeline by calling the pipeline API

[Pipeline Runs - Query By Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/query-by-factory?tabs=HTTP)

Get your id from this call, you can pass filters to limit number of runs received to get your target one.

Then call the pipeline runs api passing your runId and you get the status of the run.

[Pipeline Runs - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/pipeline-runs/get?tabs=HTTP)

Sample response

```
{
  "runId": "2f7fdb90-5df1-4b8e-ac2f-064cfa58202b",
  "pipelineName": "examplePipeline",
  "parameters": {
    "OutputBlobNameList": "[\"exampleoutput.csv\"]"
  },
  "invokedBy": {
    "id": "80a01654a9d34ad18b3fcac5d5d76b67",
    "name": "Manual"
  },
  "runStart": "2018-06-16T00:37:44.6257014Z",
  "runEnd": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
  "durationInMs": 28105,
  "status": "Succeeded",
  "message": "",
  "lastUpdated": "2018-06-16T00:38:12.7314495Z",
  "annotations": []
}
```

You can see the status is "Succeeded"
It would be one of InProgress, Succeeded, and Failed.